# "Nearest to point" query with additional constraint

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a relatively standard Parse query to obtain the nearest items in the 'checkIn' class to an object's location as follows:

```
var checkInObject = Parse.Object.extend('checkIn');
var query = new Parse.Query(checkInObject);
query.near('location', request.object.get('location'));
query.limit(Parse.User.current().get('limit'));
```

This works as expected, however can return checkins of the user carrying out the request.  To avoid this I add in an additional constraint so my code now looks like this:

```
var checkInObject = Parse.Object.extend('checkIn');
var query = new Parse.Query(checkInObject);
query.near('location', request.object.get('location'));
query.notEqualTo('user', Parse.User.current());
query.limit(Parse.User.current().get('limit'));
```

But with this addition I no longer receive any results from the query.  How can I add the constraint and still obtain the required results?

Comment: can you in plain english describe what you want from the query so we can help you construct it ? or you just want so skip current user ? btw notEqualTo is kind of expensive query operator slowing things down ...

Comment: The above is an example of the titular issue, which is that any query with both `near` and an additional constraint in it fails.  After some discussion with the parse folks it appears that it might be a bug in their product, but in the meantime a generic workaround to a `near` with additional `notEqualTo` constraint would be nice (note that the `notEqualTo` could be `doesNotMatchQuery` for more complex examples)

Comment: Can you post a sample of what the raw query data returned looks like? Before any filtering, including columns headers & all columns.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

Add a string column called "ownerID" and assigned each checkin the value of the objectId of the parse user that created it. Then, you can do this:

```
var checkInObject = Parse.Object.extend('checkIn');
var query         = new Parse.Query(checkInObject);
query.near('location', request.object.get('location'));
query.limit(Parse.User.current().get('limit'));

query.notEqualTo('ownerID', Parse.User.current().get('objectId'));
```

You're also gonna want to make sure that the line where you get 'limit' returns a valid value.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this isn't the issue; the issue is that combining a `near()` with any other constraint appears to cause the query to fail.